# Where is the ibm http server admin server located

Tags: websphere

I just installed the websphere application server 8.5 base trial version. I created some profile and during the creation I was given the option to create an web server. Now from the admin console of the application server, I select the web server and try to stop it (which already started via windows service) and I get this error:

Could not make a connection to the IBM HTTP Administration server on node WIN-59G1QOTRGAMNode05/webserver1.

So I am trying to locate this darn admin server.

I checked the properties of the web server from the application server and found this:

WEBSERVER_ADDRESS  80
WEBSERVER_ADMIN_ADDRESS  8008

So there must be something at this port. Okay I try this:

http://{localhost}:8008

whoa!! No page found.

I try this:

http://{localhost}

Okay I get something. A web page with link "Administration". I click that and what I get? A help topic titled "Starting and stopping the IBM HTTP Server administration server" and what it's suggested:

From the Start menu:
Click Start > Programs > IBM HTTP Server > Start Administration Server. A message box displays that indicates the server has started.

I go to program > ibm http server. Nothing of Administration server is mentioned. There is one menu item "start http server". Okay I click that and what I get? An error message: the port 80 is already bound and can't be reused. Obviously this is not the administration server.

Another option suggested:

◦If the IBM HTTP Server administration server does not start, complete the following steps:
1.Open the Control Panel.
2.Click Services.
3.Double-click IBM HTTP Server Administration Server to start the server.

I opened the windows service and there is no such thing as Administration server.

So how to get out of  this loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is usually in the C:/WebSphere8.5/IHS/bin

Or you can check the properties of the Windows Service that starts your current Web server, to see the exact location. Additionally, check if you got an HTTP_Admin service already.